# Retrieve data from another Windows runtime apps

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have two WinRT Apps. I want to open second WinRT app from first app and get the data from second app to first app. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Depending on the type of data. When I had two apps communicating, I used an XML file and had an event that fired when the last saved date on the file was edited. If it was edited, then the other application would pull in the data from that xml file. This is one method, it's not perfect but it worked for my specific scenario. You can also try to implement sockets in each of the apps to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, here is how to do it:

In both app (let's call them app_A and app_B), you define the active protocol for them. So app_A will handle app_A:// protocol and app_B will handle app_B:// protocol.

In app_A, you press a button (for the sake of this sample), launch url: app_B://{your query here}.

app_B will handle your query, prepare returning data, and launch url app_A://{returning data here}.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to launch second app? Can you provide some code snippet? `await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mySecondAppName"));` I tried this but didn't work

Comment: await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri({your protocol here}));

e.g:

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("app_A://"));

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, but with the new APIs on Windows 10  we can more 'communicate' between apps.